# Using the previous row without using a loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to calculate a row using the previous row. However, I don't want to use a loop because it increases run time.

Here's an example of what I'm attempting to do.

| Date | V1 | V2 | ... V50000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31/2021 | 1.5442 | 1.1247 | 1.87568 |
| 1/7/2022 | 1.5442 * norm(1,.5) | 1.1247 * norm(1.,5) | 1.87568 * norm(1,5) |
| ...12/31/2023 | .... | ... | .... |

Comment: In this case you could use `cumprod` - to get the first 10 values of V1 you could do `cumprod(c(1, rnorm(9, 5))) * 1.5442`

Comment: The only issue with this is that I want to a different normal random variable for each column.

Comment: Maybe you can use `map()`, `dmap()` or `apply()` combined with a self-written function containing `lead()` or `lag()`...

Comment: Given `x <- c(4, 5, 6)` as rnorm means and `y <- c(1.5442, 1.1247, 1.87568)`, how about `mapply(function(x, y) cumprod(c(1, rnorm(9, x))*y), x=x, y=y)`?